# Windows Docker container: SET-DATE issue

Tags: windows, docker, powershell

For test proposal need an updated date in a windows docker container, and got "A required privilege is not held by the client"

Any ideas?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGR1S.jpg)

Comment: How was your prompt launched? It's not sufficient that your account is an administrator, the PowerShell prompt also needs to be elevated so you actually have the administrative privileges.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I do:  `docker exec -it <name of container> --user ContainerAdministrator powershell` as admin via PowerShell console. I tried as well `runas /user:admin "set-date "some date"` - inside of running container no effect. (I created a new user admin in a container and added it to the Administrators group). In which group should ContainerAdministrator? how to elevate it?